# Problem regarding clock stopping when voltage goes too high...?

Tags: batteries, clock, adapter

I have a peculiar problem, that I can't explain.

The thing is, I have a clock where I have installed light so it will light up when it's dark in the room. This works fine, it's feeded by an adapter giving approximately 13 volt.

Now, the clockwork itself is operated by a battery, 1.5 V. And my philosophy is, that anything mounted at a place and not supposed to be moved should never be fed by a battery, it should have a steady source of current.

Now, the solution to this is instead of the battery, I use the current from the adapter, using a resistor and two diodes (0.6 V drop each, resulting in about 1.2 V) placed where the battery should be.

This works to a certain extent, but when the clock is placed on the wall, it have difficulties moving the hand showing the seconds when moving upwards, thus resulting in the watch to stop.

Believing that those 1.2 V is a tad to small, I put one more diode in series with the other two, resulting in about 1.6 volts. To my surprise, the clock stops working at all.

When removing the extra diode, the clock works like before, moving fine when lying down, but stops when put up on the wall.

I am completely confused by this. A higher voltage (that even simulates the battery voltage vise) it should just work as a charm.

If it can help, I can inform that it's a clock bought in China.

Diagram here:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a voltage regulator?

Comment: The clock mechanism probably needs to draw pulses of current from its supply - and this works fine even with a small battery. But that 5k6 resistor of yours prevents that. Try putting an electrolytic capacitor (maybe about 100uF) in parallel with the pair of diodes to provide the source of charge for those current pulses.

Comment: Current  should be taken in account. Your power supply can not provide sufficient current..

Answer (score 0):

I tried a resistor ten times smaller, 560 ohm. That solved the problem.

I guess I underestimated the current needed for the clock to run, which I originally measured to be 1 milliamp. The clock runs now as it should. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: That's a remarkably inefficient solution.

Comment: Scott Seidman, I know, but this was something I very fast had to clamp together, and I had to use what I just had lying around.